# Reading CSV files with url in a column

Tags: tabularray, csvsimple-13

I am using csvsimple-13 package to embed csv files as tables into my latex document.
If there are hyperlinks in one column of the CSV file (for example, the command \url), an error appears and it is not possible to create a table.

Here is my Latex code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
id, Url2
Web 1, \url{https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242381097_User-Level_Reliability_and_Quality_Monitoring_in_Satellite-Based_Personal_Navigation}
Web 2, \url{"$<$a target=""_self"" href=""/superset/dashboard/15/?native_filters=(NATIVE_FILTER-OOtXEsC1P:(__cache:(label:'DE000DGE4510',validateStatus:!f,value:!('DE000DGE4510')),extraFormData:(filters:!((col:isin,op:IN,val:!('DE000DGE4510')))),filterState:(label:'DE000DGE4510',validateStatus:!f,value:!('DE000DGE4510')),id:NATIVE_FILTER-OOtXEsC1P,ownState:()))""$>$DE000DGE4510$<$/a$>$"}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\csvreader[no head,
centered tabularray={colspec={Q[l]Q[l]}}
]{\jobname.csv}{}%
{\csvcoli& \csvcolii}
 
\end{document}
```

I can't find what's wrong. If anyone can help I would be very grateful.